# Элементы списков в качестве элементов словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, словарь

Есть два списка:

```
animals = ['monkey', 'tiger']
amount = [1, 2]
```

Есть один словарь k:

```
k = {}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при команде `print(k)` выводилось следующее:

```
{'monkey': 1, 'tiger': 2}
```

Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вдруг нужно именно пополнить существующий словарь, не затирая имеющееся содержимое, то так:

```
animals = ['monkey', 'tiger']
amount = [1, 2]

k = {}

for a,v in zip(animals, amount):
    k[a] = v

print(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
animals = ['monkey', 'tiger']
amount = [1, 2]

res = dict(zip(animals, amount))

print(res)
```